# Unable to select word on double click in tmux session

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I am trying to use tmux and but I cannot double click to select a word to copy it into the clipboard like a normal putty/kitty window. However, I am able to hold shift and double click to select a word.

I even updated the tmux to version tmux next-3.4

My machine info is as follows;

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
```